# AMD Epyc Zen 2 slowed down by spin-loop

Tags: performance, x86-64, real-time, low-latency, amd-processor

I wrote a multi-threaded SIMD matrix-vector multiplication that performs better than Intel MKL at my sizes of interest
([Multi-threaded fixed-size matrix-vector multiplication optimized for many-core CPUs with non-uniform caches](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75562672/multi-threaded-fixed-size-matrix-vector-multiplication-optimized-for-many-core-c/75678912)).

I'm mostly using AMD Zen 2 processors these days, and I observe very strange timing behavior on the AMDs. See the picture below. Before iteration "0", the multiplication has been executed 100,000 times directly one after the other and the timing for each multiplication has long settled and is rock solid. At iteration "0", I add a spin-loop between the multiplications. After less than 10 iterations, the timing then explodes and settles at a new level that is multiple times as longer. If I remove the spin-loop again, it takes dozens of iterations to speed up to the original level. I only observe this on AMD Zen 2 processors, but not on Intel Xeon SP Skylake.

[image]

I've tried with adding _mm_pause() to the spin-loop, prefetching (parts of) the matrix, as well as doing other computations in the AVX registers for spinning. Even executing the same matrix-vector multiplication over and over just with fewer columns. Nothing helped.

So far I'm concluding that whenever the CPU does anything different than the exact same full-size multiplication for even a small amount of time, the multiplication slows down a lot. This seems to happen as soon as the time between the multiplications exceeds roughly the time the CPU takes for a "hot" multiplication (TBC).

The system, both hardware and software, is tuned for low-latency, and all power saving modes etc that can adversely affect determinism are disabled and my program runs at high SCHED_FIFO priority and the threads are pinned to the CPU cores.

Does anybody have an idea what could be going on in the CPU and/or how to reach good performance even with little breaks between the multiplications?