# when to clear the TLB if using process identifier?

Tags: caching, memory, tlb

In 'Computer Organization and Design' RISC-V version [ebook](https://www.cs.sfu.ca/%7Eashriram/Courses/CS295/assets/books/HandP_RISCV.pdf) by Patterson and Hennessy p850, it says:

> A common alternative is to extend the virtual address space by
> adding a **process identifier** or task identifier. The Intrinsity FastMATH
> has an 8-bit address space ID (ASID) field for this purpose. This
> small field identifies the currently running process; it is kept in a
> register loaded by the operating system when it switches processes.
> RISC-V also offers ASID to reduce TLB flushes on context switches.
> The process identifier is concatenated to the tag portion of the TLB,
> so that a TLB hit occurs only if both the page number and the
> process identifier match. This combination eliminates the need to
> clear the TLB, **except on rare occasions**.

So what is the rare occasions? Does it refers to the rare condition that the TLB is full of translation cache of one process ? Or something else ?

Comment: By the way while that paragraph in P&H makes it sound easy, it is [difficult to use such process IDs for actual process IDs](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20155304/555045). There are too few of them (so *if* you use them that way, you need some way to recycle IDs) and there are other problems.

Comment: Thanks. 1. As the link you offered say, we 'have to do some research (experiments, prototypes, benchmarking) to determine the most effective way' like the [kernel](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/commit/?id=10af6235e0d327d42e1bad974385197817923dc1) does. 2. Although on my laptop, only '381' processes are running by checking `ps axu | wc -l`, but 'there are monster
systems with over 4096 CPUs' (the kernel link above says) and 'use all 12 PCID bits have resulted in slowdowns'.

Comment: These two factors cause 'patch uses PCID differently' which needs understanding the source codes (I will do that after learning some basic knowledge.). (PCID recycling see what ['Brendan'](https://forum.osdev.org/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=29935) says) 3. Answering to the original question, the ['TLB shootdown'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3748384/what-is-tlb-shootdown) (see 'invalidated in all of the cores' in the link) is the above 'rare occasions' (maybe not rare). It is similar to cache coherency.

Comment: Complement to the 1st element in the list: this implies the somewhat difficult implementation. Complement to the 2nd element in the list: From linux 4.14, it ['uses a PCID cache per CPU'](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41404782/21294350) which is to 'identify a recently-used mm on a per-cpu basis' as the above kernel link says. So it use PCID per-cpu instead of 'PCID per-process'. Complement to the 3rd element in the list: 'TLB shootdown' is one of the rare occasions. If my understanding is wrong, please point out. Thanks.